# Performance and Cost Analysis: Lambda vs. DynamoDB Stream for Triggering Step Functions in Idempotent Order Handling

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions, aws-serverless

I have a use case where a Lambda function handles order requests, ensuring idempotency by logging entries into DynamoDB and potentially triggering a Step Function. I am evaluating two approaches:

**Option 1**: Lambda directly triggers the Step Function based on DynamoDB entries.

**Option 2**: DynamoDB Streams trigger the Step Function asynchronously.

I am seeking factual insights based on performance and cost metrics to inform my decision. Specifically:

Latency: Which option exhibits lower latency in triggering the Step Function?

Scalability: How do the two options scale with increasing order request loads?

Cost Efficiency: Are there notable cost differences between the options, considering Lambda invocations, DynamoDB throughput, and Step Function executions?

Reliability: How do the options compare in terms of error handling and reliability?

Please share your experiences or any factual information, including performance benchmarks or documentation, to help me make an informed decision.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Option 1: Pros

- Provides excellent and predictable control of when to invoke the Step-function workflow
- Lower cost due to non existence of DynamoDB stream integration.
- Lower risk of duplicate step function invocations caused by DynamoDB streams.
- Control of step function invocation is solely managed by the Lambda.
- Provides a great way to validate/filter unwanted payloads that could invoke the order processing system.

Option 1: Cons

- Less extensible design as the invocation of the workflow is enclosed inside the function.
- Its harder to add more producers
- Single point of failure for the message production side.

Option 2: Pros

- Provides an extensible mechanism to add event producers in the future.
- Better decoupling compared to option 1 because the workflow is invoked by the DynamoDB stream and not the higher level function
- Better option if you have an existing solution that uses DynamoDB streams.

Option 2: Cons

- Higher cost due to cost incurred by using DynamoDB streaming
- Less control on when the Step function workflow is invoked
- Higher risk of unwanted invocations
- You will have to write your code to handle duplicate workflow invocations gracefully. (Idempotency)